# MaxLength does not trigger intellisense, and ignores value with invalid length in runtime

Tags: c#, attributes, data-annotations, maxlength

I have the following class and a test form:

```
 class MyTestClass
    {
        [MaxLength(1)]
       public string TestString { get; set; }
    }

    private void TestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyTestClass test = new MyTestClass();
            test.TestString = "12345";´
        }
```

As seen, I set MaxLength attribute to 1, and I assign a 5-char string to it. Yet my code compiles. And when I run the project it does not throw an exception too.

1. Why it doesnt work at all? I build it at C# .Net 4.6.1, WinForm project.
2. I want it to create an error during intellisense. 
   Like Obsolete Attribute. ([Obsolete("This function is deprecated", true)] prevents the code to be built.) How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Problem is, that Attributes were only for MVC and EntityFramework. They are nott designed to create an element in Erro List of VS.
2. Second question still stands, however as it become clear it's irrelevant, I will mark this as answer.